# How to display truncated error bars with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a quite simple question. Lets consider I have data like that:

```
plouf <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10 + 1:10*0.1, y_min = 1:10/2, y_max = (1:10)^2)
```

If I plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plouf,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y_min, ymax = y_max))
```

I get this[image]

I would like to keep a linear scale, and zoom in to see the points :

```
ggplot(plouf,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y_min, ymax = y_max))+
  ylim(0,20)
```

[image]

But here I don't see the error bars. I would like to display the truncated error bars, to show that the error is bigger than the scale displayed here, and to show the lower value of the error bar.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try: `coord_cartesian(ylim = c (0,20))`, this a dupe, will try to find a target.

Comment: thanks, exacty what I wanted. Sorry for the duplicated, I didn't find the right question

Comment: No worries, duplicated posts **are** useful, helps with different search words for the same problem.